# Filter items with .filter .map .some .indexOf etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, ecmascript-6

I'm building a recipe generator in react.js and es6.
Im trying to filter the recipes in a good way and right now I'm just checking if my recipes includes any of the choosen ingredients.

I want it to first check if my Baseingredient is in the recipe-ingredient array and then filter the rest after that is done. So the baseingredient **MUST** be included.

The baseingredient and the choosen ingredients are all in the same ingredientArray(cartIds), so the "cartIds" also includes the Id of my currentBaseingredient.

**This is what my code looks like today.**

```
const recipes = () => {
  return { recipes: Store.getRecipes(), cart: Store.getCart(), baseingredient: Store.getCurrentBaseIngredient() }
}

const Recipes = ( props ) => {
  var cartIds = props.cart.map(item => item.ingredientId); // Ex: [11, 23, 1]

  // TODO: this ingredient-id must be in the recipes ingredient array!!
  var baseIngredient = props.baseingredient.ingredientId;
  console.log('baseingredient id:',baseIngredient); // Ex: 1

  var recipes = props.recipes
    .filter(recipe => ( // Run filter function on all recipes
      recipe.ingredients.some(ingredient => ( // Check if reciepe contains any of the chosen ingredients
        cartIds.indexOf(ingredient.ingredientId) >= 0) // Ingredient check
      )
    )) // Now we have a list of reciepes which contain some of the chosen ingredients
    .map( ( recipes, i ) => {
      return (
        <RecipesItem
          key={i}
          recipe={recipes}/>
        )
    } );
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Recipe</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {recipes}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, My question is, how can I include that my baseindredient is in the filter function ? @zerkms

Comment: @CeciliaFredriksson: Just test for it? What exactly is the problem you're stuck at?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like below what you need? Also you were missing the `return` keyword in your filter before

```
var recipes = props.recipes
          .filter(recipe => ( // Run filter function on all recipes
              return recipe.ingredients.includes(baseIngredient) && recipe.ingredients.some(ingredient => ( // Check if reciepe contains any of the chosen ingredients
                cartIds.indexOf(ingredient.ingredientId) >= 0) // Ingredient check
              )
            ))  // Now we have a list of reciepes which contain some of the chosen ingredients
        .map( ( recipes, i ) => {
          return (
            <RecipesItem
              key={i}
              recipe={recipes}/>
            )
        } );
```

Comment: I didn't totally understood your question, but seems that you definitely want the baseIngredient to be included, so use filter and && to build up your predicate

Comment: I want to show all the recipes that includes the baseingredients and some other ingredients. =)

Comment: Cool, so does the above not work for you? I realise i made a typo initially, having typed "include" rather than "includes"

Comment: hehe yes, I noticed that too, but it doesn't seem to work :/ Now it doesn't show any of my recipes :P